# how to set Headquarters in schema.org json ld

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

this is my json ld

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "legalName" : "example",
  "url" : "https://www.example.com/",
  "description" : "Company",
  "logo" : "logo.jpg",
  "sameAs" : [ " https://www.facebook.com/example"]
}
</script>
```

for Headquarters what attribute need to be used?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such property like Headquarters. But there are some possibilities to display relations between different offices and organization levels. Look further to following properties:

- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contact
- https://schema.org/department
- https://schema.org/foundingLocation
- https://schema.org/parentOrganization
- https://schema.org/subOrganization

Related to your screenshot:

Informations from your screenshot are actually coming from Wiki / DBpedia entry for the firm. If you look at this page http://dbpedia.org/page/Google you will see, the Headquarters information from your screenshot is actually a kind of location property, like on my screenshot:

[image]

Comment: above i added image please look into it

Comment: :) for this you (or somebody else) should maintain a wiki / dbpedia entry for your company. i've updated my post.